# React router v4 history.push to the same route (different query params) in Functional Component (use Hooks API)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-v4, react-hooks

I am trying to code search filter feature for table. I am using react-router-dom v4. 
When user click search button, I want to navigate page from "/list" to "list?search=abc" by props.history.push(). (I already used RouteComponentProps and withRouter).
But I know react-router-dom v4 just changes url while it doesn't not refresh the page.
My colleague uses function componentWillReceiveProps in class component to detect query params changes. (now that function is known as getDerivedStateFromProps)

```js
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   console.log("next Props");
   if (nextProps.location.search !== this.props.location.search) {
     let parsed = queryString.parse(nextProps.location.
     this.loadData(parsed);
   }
```

Using React Hook (with Typescript) in functional component is compulsory to me. I tried many ways but it didn't work.
Do you know the way to figure this issue out?
Thank you very much.

Comment: I found my solution, I use useEffect to detect change search 


useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`use effect set state search`);
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search);
    console.log(`search params: ${searchParams}`);
    const search = searchParams.get("search") || "";

    console.log(`search: ${search}`);

    setState({ ...state, search: search });

    loadData(search);
  }, [new URLSearchParams(props.location.search).get("search")]);

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer rather than a comment. Then you can accept your own answer and it will be clearer to others that this question is already answered.

Comment: I have done it, thank you for reminding me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my solution, I use useEffect to detect query params search change

```js
useEffect(() => { 
  console.log(`use effect set state search`);
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search); console.log(search params: ${searchParams}); 
  const search = searchParams.get("search") || "";
  console.log(search: ${search}); setState({ ...state, search: search }); 
  loadData(search); 
}, [props.location.search]);
```